# Cómo generar un número siempre y cuando no exista

Tags: javascript

Me gustaria generar un número que no exista en el *div* con la clase **exist** si existe pues que no lo genere.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }
    
    counter = getRandomInt(1, 500);
    
    
    
    var a = document.querySelector(".exist");
    
    var b = document.querySelector(".new");
    
    
    
    b.innerText = counter;
    
    
    
    function comprobate() {
    
    
    if (a.innerText == b.innerText) {
    
    }
    
    
    }
```

```html
<span class="exist">45</span>

<br/>

<br/>

<br/>


<span class="new"></span>



<br/>
<br/>


<button onclick="comprobate()">Comprobar</button>
```

Comment: Mientras no lo generes, no existe. Supongo que te refieres a evitar la generación de un número previamente generado. Para tal situación se realiza un proceso de barajado de números previamente generados, luego escoges un valor al azar y lo eliminas de la baraja. Cuando necesitas otro número, vuelves a barajar y seleccionas uno al azar. Así hasta agotar toda la baraja. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

para saber si el numero es igual al que esta en el div exist tienes que forzosamente generarlo, ahora si lo que quieres es que si el numero generado es igual al existente no lo pinte en el div new, entonces esto serviria

```
let counter;
        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        }

        counter = getRandomInt(1, 500);



        var a = document.querySelector(".exist");

        var b = document.querySelector(".new");

        b.textContent = counter;

        function comprobate() {


            if (parseInt(a.textContent) == parseInt(b.textContent)) {
                console.log("es igual");
                b.textContent = "";
            } else {
                console.log("no es igual");    
            }
        }
```